# Can not precompiled my views using VS2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

Using the latest VS 2019, I am trying to publish my new MVC site to my production server.
By default, I didn't precompile during publishing and it was working fine.
Now I would like to precompile my views in order to avoid the delay at the first request as some views are quite complex.
When I check "Precompile during publishing" and I uncheck "Allow precompiled site to be updatable", the publication failed and hundreds of errors are shown in my views that were not shown before or during the builds.
If I check "Allow precompiled site to be updatable", the publication works fine and I have no error.

Some of the errors are:

```
Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration on  data_width = Model.Width
Feature 'expression-bodied method' is not available in C# 4
```

This errors appears only when The "Allow precompiled site to be updataable" is unchecked.
They are shown for .cshtml views in  the \obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\Views folder.
The build works fine, the default publication works fine. I am using VS2019 and have specified version 7 for C# so it is quite inconsistent...

How can I publish precompiled views that I don't want to be updatable without error?

Comment: Can you give us some examples of the errors? Are they genuine problems with your code, problems with the precompiler build environment / dependencies, something else?

Comment: I have added some example of errors but I have specified C# to be version 7 so I don't understand why they are occuring...